# Debugging Silverlight in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, silverlight, debugging, breakpoints

I have an MVC application which uses a silverlight control.

Somewhere along the line something is happening in the silverlight cs code that isn't right. I've inserted break points in the CS silverlight code to get a better idea of what's happening, but for some reason I just can't step through the code.

I know code is being hit, but it's just not showing me in the debugger.

I thought it might be because I was using Chrome as the default browser but I changed this to Internet Explorer and still no joy.

I realize this is a very vague question, but has anyone else experience anything similar, and if so, how did you get around it?

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: Did you set IE as default in VS (not OS), such that when you hit F5 it launches IE?

Comment: Hi Jay. I didn't set it as default from within VS, however when I hit F5 it does launch IE.

Comment: I'd expect that to work, but try this: add an aspx or html file to your project, right-click it and select Browse With…, and then set the default to IE. My only other suggestion is to put the SL control into a SL project for debugging purposes -- suboptimal, I know.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Be sure to set the Silverlight Debugging checkbox on the project properties Web tab

Answer (score 4):

If Chrome is your default browser and your breakpoint tooltip shows this message:

"The breakpoint will not currently be hit.  No symbols have been loaded for this document"

... then it is possible the debugger attached to the wrong Chrome process at debug startup.  A work-around is:

1. Start debugging your Silverlight app.  Your app should be running in Chrome.
2. From the  Debug menu, select Attach to Process...
3. Scroll through the available processes and locate the chrome.exe process that shows the type as 'Silverlight x86'.
4. Select that process and click Attach.

Answer (score 3):

I had firefox as my default browser and nothing was being hit(I even tried attaching to a process).  What finally worked for me was setting IE as the default.

Silverlight break points are now being hit for me! :)

Comment: Yep! http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/make-ie-default-browser#ie=ie-11

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on Web.UI project in solution. go to Web , check Debuggers --> Silverlight save and Debug..
Make sure you have silverlight developer installed.

Answer (score -1):

Your code may be part of a class marked with the `System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute`. This happens with auto generated classes (like with Add Service Reference). If you are extending a partial class, other parts of the class definition may have that attribute.

Try unckecking the `Options / Debugging / General / Enable Just My Code` checkbox.

Otherwise put your mouse over the red dot in the source code window, which becomes an empty circle if the debugger disabled it, a tooltip will give you additional information.